# What does rolling do for Fish?

Tags: nuclear-throne

Fish can roll, yes, but how is it useful? [The wikia](http://nuclear-throne.wikia.com/wiki/Fish) says it doesn't block damage, but it calls this ability "Dodge Roll". I played as Fish a bit but couldn't figure out the useful aspect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The general consensus is that this skill is somewhat hard to use and learn, however if used correctly, it can be a significant help. The main uses for it are dodging bullets, and moving fast. The combination of these two uses allow for you reposition yourself into a useful location, such as into melee range while dodging bullets. You can also use your weapons while rolling.

[Here](http://steamcommunity.com/app/242680/discussions/0/45350790949986572/) is a nice discussion about whether or not it is useful.